# Can a Windows dll retrieve its own filename?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, dll, path

A Windows process created from an exe file has access to the command string that invoked it, including its file's path and filename. eg. `C:\MyApp\MyApp.exe --help`.

But this is not so for a DLL invoked via `LoadLibrary`. Does anyone know of a way for a function loaded via DLL to find out what its path and filename are?

Specifically, I'm interested in a solution using the Delphi Programming Language, but I suspect that the answer would be pretty much the same for any language.

Comment: *"A Windows process created from an exe file has access to the command string that invoked it, including its file's path and filename."* - That's not correct. It is a *convention* only. Have a look at the documentation for [`CreateProcessW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) to learn how to launch a process that receives a command line with arbitrary content.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I think you're looking for GetModuleFileName.

http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/torry/showcode.php?id=143:

```
{
  If you are working on a DLL and are interested in the filename of the
  DLL rather than the filename of the application, then you can use this function:
}

function GetModuleName: string;
var
  szFileName: array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
begin
  FillChar(szFileName, SizeOf(szFileName), #0);
  GetModuleFileName(hInstance, szFileName, MAX_PATH);
  Result := szFileName;
end;
```

Untested though, been some time since I worked with Delphi :)

Comment: As of Delphi XE, `GetModuleName` is defined in the *System.pas* unit

Comment: In Delphi 6, `Windows` is required in `uses` clause for definition of `MAX_PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

### Delphi XE+

In newer versions of Delphi, you can simply use the `GetModuleName` function from `System.SysUtils`. You simply pass in `hInstance` as the parameter.

So the full code would be `GetModuleName(hInstance)` to get the DLL filename path.

### Older than Delphi XE

With older versions of Delphi, you need to write your own function for this:

```
function GetModuleName: string;
var
  sFileName: array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
begin
  FillChar(sFileName, SizeOf(sFileName), #0);
  GetModuleFileName(hInstance, sFileName, MAX_PATH);
  Result := sFileName;
end;
```